# How to get value with dictionary (dictfetchall) from multiple cursor separated?

Tags: python

I have multiple query like these:

```
query_a = "select * from A"
query_b = "select * from B"
```

then i want to execute these 2 queries

```
a = self.cr.execute(query_a)
b = self.cr.execute(query_b)
```

and save them in separated dictionary like these but give me error:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

```
all_lines = self.cr.dictfetchall()[0]
all_lines1 = self.cr.dictfetchall()[1]
```

So how to save value from different queries to dictionaries separated??

Comment: Pls share your output received and desired output

Comment: What is `dictfetchall`?